# What is the difference between the various elemental symbols?

Tags: genshin-impact

While playing Genshin Impact this morning, I noticed something I had never noticed before. I took a small hiatus, so I’m not sure if this is something new or I was just oblivious to it.

On the character profile, the characters elemental type is displayed on the top-left of the screen. While going through my characters, I saw there are two types of symbols for each element

[image: Geo type 1] [image: Geo type 2]

[image: Electro type 1] [image: Electro type 2]

What are the differences between the two? Does it have anything to do with the character (range/physical/magic)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is about the vision model / region. If you notice, Beidou and Ningguang have the same "square" shell, while Noelle and Lisa use the winged crest. Beidou and Ningguang both come from Liyue, while Noelle and Lisa are from Mondstadt.

Mondstadt has the three wings vision.
[image]

Liyue has the square "geode" vision.

[image]

Inazuma has the circular design reminiscent of the drums usually associated to [Raijin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raijin) in Japanese mythology and the Shinto religion (also known as Raiden-sama... guess how is the Archeon called)

[image]

Snezhnaya has the pointy design based on I-don't-know-what.

[image]

Interesting enough, Mona vision is of Mondstadt design. Kaeya's...

[image]

Comment: Kaeya received his vision while he was a citizen of Mondstadt though, which explains why he doesn't have a Khaenri'ahn vision design.

Comment: look better Tartagl... @childe, his vision design is very close to a Mondstadt one but does not fully match. On his version there are only two side wings instead of three.

Comment: It's a very minor difference, because the main motif of Mondstadt visions are the wings, representing freedom.